# Access ResourceDictionary from Code(not Code-Behind)

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, resourcedictionary

in my application, i have a resource dictionary defined as a separate file. Now i want to access this dictionary from a c#-file (**no code-behind file!**)

What would be the best(fastest, cleanest) way to do this?

- Create a ResourceDictionary in code and merge it with the existing one?
- Add the ResourceDictionary to the application's resources and access
  them with Application.Current.Resources?
- Some other way??

Greets,

Jürgen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can load resource dictionaries using App.LoadComponent(), e.g.:

```
var d = (ResourceDictionary)App.LoadComponent(new Uri("Dictionary1.xaml",UriKind.Relative));
```

Not really sure if it would be the fastest, but it is probably one of the cleaner ways.